# Ordinal pair $(α,β)$ such that $α<β$ and $Th(α,<) = Th(β,<)$

Tags: model-theory, ordinals

A number of weeks ago I was thinking of finding an example of a complete countable theory with only one binary predicate that is not $ω$-categorical. I later realized that $Th(\mathbb{Z},<)$ works, but an earlier thought was to find two non-isomorphic well-orders that have the same first-order theory. This sparked the question of what are all such pairs, and what is the smallest such pair.

I think $(ω^ω,ω^ω+ω^ω)$ is the smallest such pair (since $ω^k$ all don't work for finite $k$, by the winning strategy of David C. Ullrich in the comments below), but how to prove it? Is there a generalized criterion for determining when $Th(α,<) = Th(β,<)$ given two arbitrary ordinals $α,β$?

Comment: Very nice question! I almost recall that there is a known answer, and I can almost recall that I saw it somewhere. But I'm too tired to actually recall either of these things.

Comment: Are you sure that $(\omega^2,\omega^2+\omega^2)$ _is_ such a pair? Seems to me we can "say" "$x$ is a limit ordinal", and similarly we can "say" $x$ is a limit of limit ordinals. Now $\omega^2+\omega^2$ has an element which is a limit of limit ordinals, while $\omega^2$ does not. (Or I'm all wet about all this - that's always a possibility...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Indeed you can say "is a left-limit" by saying "has no left neighbour", but I'm pretty sure you cannot say "is a left-limit of left-limits" in first-order logic.

Comment: ??? "for every $y<x$ there exists $z$ with $y<z<x$" says $x$ is a limit ordinal, right? Now why doesn't "there exists a limit ordinal less than $x$, and for every limit ordinal $y$ less than $x$ there exists a limit ordinal $z$ with $y<z<x$" say $x$ is a limit of limit ordinals?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Ahh you win. Let me change pair.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm glad you like my question. Though I'm amused that someone lost a like for my other question at almost the same time. =P

Comment: So in particular the theory characterzes the number of limit ordinals (as $0$, $1$, $2$, ... or "infinitely many"). It also characterizes the number of limit-limit ordinals, and the number of limit-limit-limit ordinals, etc.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yea that's why I jumped to $ω^ω$. Hopefully it works now. =D

Answer (score 2):

The following is true for all $\alpha, \beta >0$:
$$Th(\omega^{\omega}\cdot \alpha,<)=Th(\omega^{\omega}\cdot \beta,<)$$
This and many related things including your conjecture can be proved using Erhenfeucht-Fraisse games. See Rosenstein: Linear Orderings.

Comment: Oh really? That's nice to know! Thanks! I think I get the gist, but better still if you can give a brief sketch. =)

Comment: Do you understand how Ehrenfeucht -Fraisse games work ? Its a bit much to explain. And the proof if this statement reduces to other lemmas about $\omega^k$.

Comment: I went to read the Wikipedia article about them after seeing your answer, and it sort of makes sense, though I haven't thought very carefully about it yet. I think I see that $α+ω^k$ can be identified by a first-order formula for any finite $k$ or $k = ω$, and that is the crucial bit to completely solve my problem, am I right?

Comment: read Rosenstein.